# Sql Server 2019 Polybase feature issue

Tags: sql-server, polybase, azure-data-studio, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to configure PolyBase on SQL Server 2019 to test some new features.

I already installed this feature and performed all steps from below instruction:
[Install PolyBase on Windows](http://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-installation?view=sql-server-2017)

I get an error notification when trying to configure connection to external table in Azure Data Studio:

[image: Azure Data Studio error]

I cannot start the SQL Server PolyBase Engine service, maybe it has something to do in this case:

[image: Sql Server Configuration Manager error]

Any ideas how to configure it properly to use PolyBase?

Comment: Did you consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details?

Comment: I got following error in Event Log:

Comment: The SQL Server PolyBase Data Movement (MSSQLSERVER01) service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 7260000 milliseconds: Restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable TCP/IP for this SQL Server before starting the services

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- enable TCP/IP as network protocol for your SQL Server instance.
- Restart the SQL Instance Restart the Polybase services.
- Enable PolyBase on the instance: `exec sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled', @configvalue = 1; RECONFIGURE;`.

You can read more about this in following two blog posts:

- https://nielsberglund.com/2019/11/20/fix-polybase-in-sql-server-2019-developers-edition/
- https://nielsberglund.com/2019/12/30/more-polybase-issues-in-sql-server-2019-developers-edition/